# How to push elements in JSON from javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I want to add javascript array values into JSON values object. The other element is also replaced my element like recipients, subject, message. I got Json like:

[image]

**Below is my code.**

```
var BODY = {
    "recipients": {
      "values": [
     ]
    },
   "subject": title,
   "body": message
}

var values = [];
for (var ln = 0; ln < names.length; ln++) {
var item1 = {
    "person": {
            "_path": "/people/"+names[ln],
            },
};
values.push(item1);
}
BODY = JSON.stringify({values: values});
alert(BODY);
```

Comment: What is your question exactly, can you rephrase it ?

Comment: Hey buddy, it's not nice to use alerts, if you do forget them. Try console.log, a better and a safe method.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you want to make objects from array and combine it with an old object (BODY.recipients.values), if it's then you may do it using `$.extent` (because you are using `jQuery`/tagged) method after prepare the object from array

```
var BODY = {
    "recipients": {
        "values": []
    },
    "subject": 'TitleOfSubject',
    "body": 'This is the message body.'
}

var values = [],
names = ['sheikh', 'muhammed', 'Answer', 'Uddin', 'Heera']; // for testing
for (var ln = 0; ln < names.length; ln++) {
    var item1 = {
        "person": { "_path": "/people/"+names[ln] }
    };
    values.push(item1);
}

// Now merge with BODY
$.extend(BODY.recipients.values, values);
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/hPMEG/1/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with the way you're populating the values array,
you can then assign this array like so:

```
BODY.values = values;
```

after the loop.

It should look like this:

```
var BODY = {
    "recipients": {
      "values": [
     ]
    },
   "subject": title,
   "body": message
}

var values = [];
for (var ln = 0; ln < names.length; ln++) {
var item1 = {
    "person": {
            "_path": "/people/"+names[ln],
            },
};
values.push(item1);
}
BODY.values = values;
alert(BODY);
```

JSON.stringify() will be useful once you pass it as parameter for an AJAX call.
Remember: the values array in your BODY object is different from the var values = [].
You must assign that outer values[] to BODY.values. This is one of the good things about OOP.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access `BODY.values`:

```
for (var ln = 0; ln < names.length; ln++) {
  var item1 = {
    "person": {
      "_path": "/people/"+names[ln],
    },
  };

  BODY.values.push(item1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [ 'a', 'b', 'c'];
arr.push('d'); // insert as last item
```