# How to generate JSON dynamically with dynamic properties?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a HTML dinamically created table that should be filled by the user.
The user can creates a new **SECTION** (as many as he want) and he can creates **LABELS** and its **TRANSLATIONS**. As many as he wants.
Following is part of the html code:

```
<table>

    <tr class = "section">
        <td class = "sectionName">section1</td>;
        <td><input type="submit" value="Update"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="lbl_trans_Wrap">
        <td class="lbl">lbl_11</td>
        <td class="trans"><input type="text" value="trans_11"></td>
    </tr>


    <tr class = "section">
        <td class = "sectionName">section2</td>;
        <td><input type="submit" value="Update"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="lbl_trans_Wrap">
        <td class="lbl">lbl_21</td>
        <td class="trans"><input type="text" value="trans_21"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="lbl_trans_Wrap">
        <td class="lbl">lbl_22</td>
        <td class="trans"><input type="text" value="trans_22"></td>
    </tr>

    ... 

</table>
```

Than I would like to create a JSON from the values filled by the user.
The object should be like this one:

```
var lang =
{
     section1:
            {
              lbl_11:"trans_11"                         
            },
     section2:
            {
              lbl_21:"trans_21",
              lbl_22:"trans_22"                          
            } 
};
```

To generate the above JSON I am using the following javascript:

```
var lang ={};
var lbl="";
var trans="";  
var section="";     

$( "tr" ).each(function() {//Pass trough each line in the table

       if($(this).hasClass( "section" )){                 
           section = $(this).children("td.sectionName").html();//Grab all sections                   
           //console.log(section);
       }
       if($(this).hasClass( "lbl_trans_Wrap" )){
            lbl = $(this).children("td.lbl").html();//Grab all labels
            //console.log(lbl);
            trans = $(this).children("td.trans").children("input.txt_translate").val();//Grab all translation
            //console.log(trans);
            lang[section]={lbl:trans};                    
       }

 });

//console.log(lang);
```

But the JSON is not being created as expected.

There are 2 issues here:

1. The **lang[section]={lbl:trans}** is overriding the last one. So at the end of the process we have only the last one element.
2. The **lbl** variable is not being recognized as variable but as a string.

Looks like this:

```
var lang =
{
     section1:
            {
              lbl:"trans_11"                         
            },
     section2:
            {
              lbl:"trans_21"                         
            } 
};
```

I've tried suggestions from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383070/json-array-pushing) and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19064487/how-to-push-elements-in-json-from-javascript-array).
But they do not use dynamically created [property](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_definition.asp). 
I've tried to use push but it not works to objects.
I could create a JSON string and then to [parse](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) it.
But I would like to know how to solve this issue in another way.
Any idea in how to generate this JSON dynamically ?

**UPDATE:**

After James's post, this is the code that works:

```
$( "tr" ).each(function() {//Pass trough each line in the table

       if($(this).hasClass( "section" )){                 
           section = $(this).children("td.sectionName").children("h1").html();//Grab all sections                   
           //console.log(section);
       }
       if($(this).hasClass( "lbl_trans_Wrap" )){
            lbl = $(this).children("td.lbl").html();//Grab all labels
            //console.log(lbl);
            trans = $(this).children("td.trans").children("input.txt_translate").val();//Grab all translation
            //console.log(trans);

            if (!lang[section]) {
              lang[section] = {};
            }
            lang[section][lbl] = trans;
       }

 });

//console.log(lang);
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using actual form fields? You could then pretty easily use something like [serializeArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery)

Comment: Hi friend, 2 reasons: 1- Sometimes we must make choices. In this case I have no choice. I am working in a project that was not written by my hand. So If I decide to rewrite from the scratch would be a long way. This is why I choose to continue the code. 2- I prefer to learn what I don't know. Now I know how to create a JSON completely dynamic, thanks to James.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are two bugs, one you are overwriting the value of `lang[section]` with a new object each time.  Two, that new object contains a key with the string value "lbl", not the value contained in the `lbl` variable.
To fix, replace:

```
lang[section]={lbl:trans};
```

With:

```
if (!lang[section]) {
  lang[section] = {};
}
lang[section][lbl] = trans;
```